# Maclaurin expansion of $\cos(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

The answer seems to be $1 - \frac{1}{2x^2} + O(\frac{1}{x^4})$.  But what happens to the terms $\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ and $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ as $x=0$?

Comment: I'd say that's a Laurent series, not a Maclaurin series. These functions have an essential singularity at $x=0$.

Comment: Here, we do not have $x\rightarrow 0$, but $x\rightarrow \infty$. With a substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$, you just get the Mac-Laurin-series for $\cos(u)$ or $\sin(u)$ for $u\rightarrow 0$. Plugging $\frac{1}{x}$ into $u$ gives the desired expansion.